# iphone default alert not being set on new calendar events created from mail

Tags: ios, email, calendar, alert

I have the default alert time for events turned on, set to 30 minutes before. This works if I create a new event from within the calendar. However, if I create a new event following a link from email, the default alert is NOT set.

Is this a known bug or is there some other setting I need to turn on? It occurs either with apple's default Mail or with Mailbox.app, so it seems to be an issue with "Create Event" as opposed to with the particular app.